# Django 1.8.3: Showing many-to-many additional fields in template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have the following problem: A project can have multiple Roles, How do I show the roles field in a template? project.role shows blank and the problem is even after using `_set.all` in the template, I still do not get the contents from the database to show.

## Model.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    """
    Information for each Project
    """

    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

    project_description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    project_url = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    #For Admin Purposes and filtering, to keep track of new and old  in the database by administrative users
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Date added'))
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Last modified'))



class Role(models.Model):
    """
    Information for Role
    """

    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    project_role = models.ManyToManyField(Project)
```

## View.py

```
class ProjectView(ListView):

    template_name = '_projects.html'

    model = Project

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['projects'] = Project.objects.all()


        return context
```

## Template

```
 {% for project_info in projects %}

        {{project_info.project_name}}
        </br>
        {{project_info.project_description}}
        </br>
        {{project_info.project_url}}
        </br>

        {% for rolling in project_info.project_role_set.all %}
            {{rolling}}
        {% endfor %}


   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for rolling in project_info.role_set.all %}
        {{rolling}}
    {% endfor %}
```